# Python's collections.defaultdict returns default value correctly unless the key isn't referenced first

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, collections

Basically if I set a `defaultdict` and reference it by key it will work fine and return the value that I set as default.  However if I use a `.get()` on it the default value is not returned.  Here is the simplest example I can give of it.

```
basedict = defaultdict(dict)
assert(basedict['junk'] == {}) # Pass
assert(basedict.get('junk') == {}) # Pass
assert(basedict.get('popcorn') == {}) # Fail
```

---

For completion, I was working with dicts of dicts and my code where I initially encountered the problem looked a bit more like this

```
from collections import defaultdict

basedict = defaultdict(dict)
assert(basedict['junk'] == {})

basedict[69] = defaultdict(lambda: 1000)
assert(basedict[69]['junk'] == 1000)
assert(basedict[69].get('junk') == 1000)
assert(basedict[69].get('junk', 420) == 1000)

# The above works fine, but if I call .get on a default dict using a key I've
# never referenced before it returns None or the .get supplied default value
assert(basedict[69].get('garbage') == 1000) # Returns None
assert(basedict[69].get('garbage', 420) == 1000) # Returns 420
assert(basedict[69].get('dumpster', 420) == 1000) # Returns 420

# But if I place a an assert before the calling .get(garbage) that 
# checks basedict[69]['garbage'] then the asserts after work until I get 
# to 'dumpster' at which point it fails again
# It also fails if I set the defaultdict to something other than a lambda
basedict[7] = defaultdict(dict)
assert(basedict[7]['taco'] == {}) # Pass
assert(basedict[7].get('taco') == {}) # Pass
assert(basedict[7].get('burrito') == {}) # Fail
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defaultdict.get()` does **not** populate the key, no. This is **by design**, as it would otherwise defeat the purpose of that method. The same applies to membership tests:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> 'foo' in d
False
>>> d['foo']
{}
>>> 'foo' in d
True
```

Use `defaultdict.__getitem__` (e.g. `defaultdict_instance[key]`) if you need the default factory to be called for missing keys.

If you needed to set a default value *other* than what the factory provides, use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> d.setdefault('bar', 42)
42
>>> d.setdefault('bar', 30)
42
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'bar': 42})
```

If all you needed was to get a default value, use `dict.get()`:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> d.get('bar', {}).get('baz', 1000)
1000
```

Note that I chained the `.get()` calls; the first `.get()` returns an empty dictionary if the first key is missing.

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem, but helped me along with finding a solution.  So I'm marking as the accepted solution.

Comment: @StackofPancakes What was your solution?

Comment: I posted my solution in the "update" section of my question.  Basically wrapped it in a try/except block to handle situations where there was no key already.

Comment: @StackofPancakes: all you needed then was `weights.get('player', {}).get(teammate, 0)`. No need to set default values *at all*.

Comment: @StackofPancakes: I rolled back the update; feel free to post your own answer post. Solutions go in answer posts, not in the question post.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem recently, and basically had to do something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class BetterDict(defaultdict):
    def get(self, item, default=None):
        # default is not really used, but leaving here for compatibility
        # This will either return the actual value, or the defaultdict's
        # default, as generated by default_factory
        return self.__getitem__(item)
```

And now:

```
basedict = BetterDict(dict)
assert(basedict['junk'] == {}) # Pass
assert(basedict.get('junk') == {}) # Pass
assert(basedict.get('popcorn') == {}) # Pass
```